Excel VBA - Loop macro over rows until empty cell
I am using a macro with a goal seek function to calculate a value in one column, based on a formula in a second column to approximate a value in a third column.
The amount of rows varies and i do not want to re-write the macro for the specific amount of rows every time i run the sheet.
See below code for goal seeking on 10 rows, but it could just as easy be 3 rows or a hundred
What i am looking for is a loop that runs the goal seek function until a empty row is encountered.
I am far from a VBA expert so i could use some help to write the proper piece of code.
Thanks in advance!
Sub GS()

    Range("O3").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P3"), ChangingCell:=Range("N3")
    Range("O4").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P4"), ChangingCell:=Range("N4")
    Range("O5").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P5"), ChangingCell:=Range("N5")
    Range("O6").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P6"), ChangingCell:=Range("N6")
    Range("O7").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P7"), ChangingCell:=Range("N7")
    Range("O8").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P8"), ChangingCell:=Range("N8")
    Range("O9").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P9"), ChangingCell:=Range("N9")
    Range("O10").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P10"), ChangingCell:=Range("N10")
    Range("O11").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P11"), ChangingCell:=Range("N11")
    Range("O12").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P12"), ChangingCell:=Range("N12")
     
End Sub


You need to know the following things:
First is the number of rows you want to handle. There are lots of different ways to figure that out, one could be to loop over the data until you find an empty row. One way can be to use CurrentRegion. Or have a look to the discussion at Find last used cell in Excel VBA
Second is you need to know how to address a cell/range per row number. Again, numerous ways. One is to use Cells rather than Range, with that you can address a cell by its row and column number. Or you write Range("P" & rowNumber), that will concatenate the letter P with the content of the variable rowNumber.
And now you loop over your data. Note that you always should tell VBA on which sheet you want to work. If you don't specify that, VBA will work on the current active sheet and that is not always the sheet that you want to use. Just keep in mind that when you use the With-clause, you need to put a "." in front of .Cells or .Range.
With ActiveSheet
'   or, for example:
' With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'   or 
' With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    With .Range("O3").CurrentRegion
        lastRow = .row + .Rows.Count - 1
    End With

    For row = 3 To lastRow
        ' Use one of the following, all do the same:
        .Range("O" & row).GoalSeek Goal:=.Range("P" & row), ChangingCell:=.Range("N" & row)
        .Cells(row, 15).GoalSeek Goal:=.Cells(row, 16), ChangingCell:=.Cells(row, 14)
        .Cells(row, "O").GoalSeek Goal:=.Cells(row, "P"), ChangingCell:=.Cells(row, "N")
    Next
End With


The code lastRow = .Range("O3").CurrentRegion.row was probably supposed to read:
With .Range("O3").CurrentRegion:  lastrow = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1:  End With

@MGonet. Thanks for the hint, you're of course right. I first wanted to show the code using a For Each row and then changed my mind - and didn't test my "change". Updated my answer
